# Sorting a list of paths in Powershell

Tags: powershell, sorting, arraylist, path

I am trying to sort (from deepest folder to root) a list of given paths.

Is there a way to achieve this with existing functions?

Example:

Given:

```
test\A\directory1
test\B
test\A\directory1\end
test\A
test\C\directory2
test
test\C
test\directdirectory
```

To obtain:

```
test\C\directory2
test\A\directory1
test\directdirectory
test\C
test\B
test\A
test
```

Comment: What is your input? Just a txt file or is it an output from another command?

Comment: Your *given* and *obtain* don't match?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an expression in your sort command to sort by the amount of `\`

```
Sort {($_ -split '\\').Count}, {$_} -Descending
```

**Example** <sub>kudos to LotPings</sub>

```
@(
'test\A\directory1'
'test\B'
'test\A\directory1\end'
'test\A'
'test\C\directory2'
'test'
'test\C'
'test\directdirectory'
) | Sort {($_ -split '\\').Count}, {$_} -Descending
```

**Result**

```
test\A\directory1\end
test\C\directory2
test\A\directory1
test\directdirectory
test\C
test\B
test\A
test
```

**Edit: is sorting on the second key necessary** <sub>the jury is still out on that</sub>

[image: Sorting on a second key difference]

Comment: Nitpicking: `| Sort-Object {($_ -split '\\').Count} -Descending` has the same result. (+1)

Comment: @LotPings - It depends on OP's needs but I assumed the resulting groups should also be sorted descending but perhaps you meant *shortening* the solution and in that case, thank you. I had no idea ;)

Comment: I did test with `PSItem` as 2nd key (without {scriptblock}) but that had the very same output as my suggestion.

Comment: @LotPings - It does not for me. Without explicitly sorting on the 2nd key, the `test\B` comes before `test\A`. Perhaps this is similar to how a database works when you don't specify a sort order: the result can be in any order but most of the time it wil return the results ordered on it's (indexed) primary key.